# Git pull, python pyc files -error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git, github

On my ec2 instance, I am trying to do a pull requests of my github repo.  I get the below error.  On my local machine I commit everything.  How do I deal with pyc files if that is the issue?

```
git add .
git commit -m 't'
git push origin development

git pull
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 1), reused 2 (delta 1)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
From https://github.com/me/rtbopsConfig
   8e320f6..0565407  development -> origin/development
Updating 94f7f3e..0565407
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    classes/ec2/ec2Auto.pyc
    classes/redis_ha.pyc
    classes/rtbUtilities.pyc
    rtb_redis_connections/redis_connections.pyc
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't store `.pyc` files in Git. On your workstation, do

```
find . -name *.pyc -exec git rm {} \;
```

Then add a line `*.pyc` to `.gitignore`, commit all the changes and push.

On the other end (EC2), do

```
git checkout classes/ec2/ec2Auto.pyc classes/redis_ha.pyc \
             classes/rtbUtilities.pyc rtb_redis_connections/redis_connections.pyc
```

then pull.

Comment: the pyc files will not delete from the repo.

Comment: the .pyc files are still on github.  I removed the files and committed the changes. On github....I still see the .pyc files.

Comment: Are you looking at the development branch?